# Swipe Left / Right to navigate on Ionic 2 RC 2

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a couple of pages and I want to swipe left or right to navigate between them. For example my Tabs component is like :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { Search } from '../search/search';
import { Share } from '../share/share';
import { Notification } from '../notification/notification';
import { Profile } from '../profile/profile';


@Component({
  selector: 'hn-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page
  home: any = HomePage;
  search: any = Search;
  share: any = Share;
  notification: any = Notification;
  profile: any = Profile;

  constructor() { }
}
```

and I want to navigate to **Search page** from **Home Page** with a `SWIPE - LEFT` .

**Is this possible ?**

Please help !!

Comment: Try adding an 'gesture' to your ion-content, look in docs for gesture

Comment: @JoeriShoeby Thanks for the suggestion. The Gesture actually tracks Swipe Event and I can listen from my Component. But how to visually / Actually VIEWS that looks like swipe. For example the Twitter App.  Is that possible ?

Comment: Pass in an option object containing the 'animate' and 'animation' property. Look in NavController docs for more info

Comment: @JoeriShoeby Thanks again. Could you please share a code snippet ? That would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I will.later this evening

Comment: @JoeriShoeby did you make the snipped somewhere please? :)

Comment: Please take a look at https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs